# In Notepad++, using regular expressions to delete something on each line starting with a certain character?

Tags: regex, notepad++

On each line, I have a list of pdfs followed by junk. 
Like:

```
yes.pdf xxxxxx
no.pdf aewrnnta
hello.pdf aewraewr
```

I would like to make it so I get

```
yes
no
hello
```

on three separate lines

How can I do this with regex?

Answer (score 4):

Try -

`\.pdf.*` in find box

and

'' in replace box

Make sure you have the RegEx radio button checked.

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
^([^.]*)\..*
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```